# convert video into low resolution RGB32 format

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am looking for a way to convert a movie file in e.g. mov or mp4, into a low resolution RGB32 (red, green, blue, alfa) file which I could read to control an nxm LED array.
The conversion should decode a compressed format, downscale the video, and write an RGB32 format file.
Is this something I could do using ffmpeg? Or some other tool?

Comment: Don't forget about the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) community if you're looking for specific software to do this scripted or not.

Answer (score 2):

Using ffmpeg,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf format=rgba,scale=N:M -f rawvideo out.bin
```

out.bin will be a sequence of RGBA values with no header or any metadata i.e.

```
R G B A R G B A R G B A ....
```

Comment: and what about frame rate? I am guessin/hoping  RGBA is not a single frame of data, but a sequence of raw video frames?

Comment: There's no frame rate as such since it's a raw stream. You should assume the framerate of the source. Each frame is appended after the other i.e. after each NxM set of 4-tuple values starts the next frame.

Comment: nice, tried it and indeed that did the trick, thanks!

Comment: hi, the output file was not exactly what I was expecting; is there a limit to N or M? For example, coudl N=1, converting it to an 1 row by 40 column raw RGB values stream?